# How to enable Night Light on BSPWM?

Tags: window-manager, tiling, night-light

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04, which has a night light feature. But now I've installed BSPWM and am using it my window manager. BSPWM seems to ignore the Gnome configs. So how do I enable night light on it?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses the GNOME inbuilt feature, I don't know BSPWM but are you still running GNOME Shell?   The answer you're looking for maybe using something like `redshift` instead (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/redshift).  As I have multiple desktops installed (including GNOME) and want the same config for all, I found it an easy fix.

Comment: @guiverc What do you mean by "still running gnome shell"? I can run BSPWM with Gnome? I've not seen anywhere explaining anything about that. I just installed BSPWM and selected it the next time I logged in, on the Ubuntu login screen.

Comment: Sorry I don't know BSPWM, which from the WM I assume is a WM like Openbox, I've used GNOME with Openbox however that was long ago and I suspect won't work with the more modern GNOME found on 20.04. If you're using BSPWM like you would an openbox login, I'd not expect GNOME's *night light* to work, thus why I suggested an alternative way to achieve it, ie. `redshift` though it's only one alternative (just my chosen solution to having the same setup work for my multiple desktop install Lubuntu/LXQt + Xubuntu/XFCE & Ubuntu/GNOME)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu 20.04 nightlight feature is a component of the Gnome Shell desktop, and works only there. To implement night light in another desktop environment, you can use the excellent utility `redshift`. If you want a graphical interface, also install `redshift-gtk`.